# Server side authentication in MQTT Server

Tags: c#, .net, mqtt

I have tried to create MQTT Server using C#. Its work fine in my local environment.

- [MQTT Server Code](https://www.csharpcodi.com/vs2/?source=5789/xamarin-iot-samples/Hermes.Mqtt/IoTMqttTest.Server/Program.cs) package : https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Mqtt.Server/
- [MQTT Client Code](https://www.csharpcodi.com/vs2/?source=5789/xamarin-iot-samples/Hermes.Mqtt/MqttTest.Client/Program.cs) : package https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Mqtt/

Its works fine.

I have modify my code with below argument.

```
client.ConnectAsync (new MqttClientCredentials (clientId, "UserName", "Password")).Wait ();
```

I had spent couple of hours to find solution - how to authentic client. But no luck. Please anyone guide me How can I authorize every client from server side  using clientId, "UserName", "Password"

Waiting for suggestion.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Asking for guides or tutorials is off topic for Stack Overflow. You need to try and if you get stuck with something specific ask a question, but as it stands this is far too broad. It also contains 2 different questions which is also does not fit the Stack Overflow model well.

Comment: I had spent couple of hours to find solution - how to authentic client. But no luck.

Comment: The question is better, but you need to show us what you've tried on the broker side

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of the MQTTServer [Class](https://github.com/xamarin/mqtt/blob/master/src/Server/MqttServer.cs):

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates an <see cref="IMqttServer"/> over the TCP protocol, using the 
/// specified MQTT configuration to customize the protocol parameters.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="configuration">
/// The configuration used for creating the Server.
/// See <see cref="MqttConfiguration" /> for more details about the supported values.
/// </param>
/// <param name="authenticationProvider">
/// Optional authentication provider to use, 
/// to enable authentication as part of the connection mechanism.
/// See <see cref="IMqttAuthenticationProvider" /> for more details about how to implement
/// an authentication provider.
/// </param>
/// <returns>A new MQTT Server</returns>
```

This says you need to pass in an implementation of the `IMQTTAuthenticationProvider` [interface](https://github.com/xamarin/mqtt/blob/master/src/Server/IMqttAuthenticationProvider.cs) in order to add authentication. It appears you will have to implement your own Authentication backend as the package does not provide any reference implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.